Trying to replicate matrix with TikZ
I'm trying to replicate the following matrix:

Considering there are lines inside this matrix, I thought about making it using TikZ, such as follows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        every left delimiter/.style={xshift=.75em},
        every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-.75em},
    ]
    \matrix[
        matrix of math nodes,
        left delimiter=(,
        right delimiter=),
        nodes in empty cells
    ] (m) {
        a_{11} & \dots & & \dots & a_{1n} \\
        \vdots & & & & \vdots \\
        & & a_{ij} & & \\
        \vdots & & & & \vdots \\
        a_{n1} & \dots & & \dots & a_{nn} \\
    };

    \draw (m-1-3) -- (m-3-3);
    \draw (m-3-1) -- (m-3-3);
    \draw (m-3-3) -- (m-3-5);
    \draw (m-3-3) -- (m-5-3);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}

which results in
.
As you can see, the lines do not stop just before the parentheses, but just before the matrix elements (since that was precisely the setting I gave TikZ). Also, I am unable to draw the letters “i” and “j” as shown in the reference figure.
Can you please help me?

To make the lines go out further, you could specify the position within the node, e.g. \draw (m-3-3) -- (m-5-3.south);

Have a look at the nicematrix package. It has a lot of fancy tools for such kind of matrices.

for the "i" and "j" you could do something like this:
\node[yshift=2em] at (m-1-3) {j};
\node[xshift=-2em] at (m-3-1) {i};

Thanks to @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz 's suggestion and after some fiddling, I propose the following solution using the nicematrix package:
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{6}
\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row, first-col, nullify-dots, xdots/line-style={-}]
    & & & j \\
    & a_{11} & \dots & \Vdots & \dots & a_{1n} \\
    & \vdots & & & & \vdots \\
    i & \Cdots & & a_{ij} & & \Cdots \\
    & \vdots & & \Vdots & & \vdots \\
    & a_{n1} & \dots & & \dots & a_{nn} \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]

which produces the following:

